# how to store timer value in mysql db using php from stopwatch javascript without using hidden input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am developing a php simple game program where the users have to solve the puzzle. A timer will be running. Once the user solves the puzzle, he will hit the submit button. i need to store the time taken by the user in mysql db.

The timer will run using jquery, the value will be store in a hidden field. Once user submit it will get the value from the hidden field.

The problem is nowadays everyone knows how to inspect the html code, they are changing the values manually.

How do i restrict that. The timer will be running like hours minutes seconds and milli seconds.

i need to store the real finished time even with milli seconds using php. How can i achieve that ?

we will announce the winner based on the less time taken to solve the puzzle. Please advice me how can i do that ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var timeBegan = null
    , timeStopped = null
    , stoppedDuration = 0
    , started = null;

function start() {
    if (timeBegan === null) {
        timeBegan = new Date();
    }

    if (timeStopped !== null) {
        stoppedDuration += (new Date() - timeStopped);
    }
    started = setInterval(clockRunning, 10);    
}

function stop() {
    timeStopped = new Date();
    clearInterval(started);
}

function reset() {
    clearInterval(started);
    stoppedDuration = 0;
    timeBegan = null;
    timeStopped = null;
    document.getElementById("display-area").innerHTML = "00:00:00.000";
}

function clockRunning(){
    var currentTime = new Date()
        , timeElapsed = new Date(currentTime - timeBegan - stoppedDuration)
        , hour = timeElapsed.getUTCHours()
        , min = timeElapsed.getUTCMinutes()
        , sec = timeElapsed.getUTCSeconds()
        , ms = timeElapsed.getUTCMilliseconds();


    document.getElementById("display-area").value = 
        (hour > 9 ? hour : "0" + hour) + ":" + 
        (min > 9 ? min : "0" + min) + ":" + 
        (sec > 9 ? sec : "0" + sec) + "." + 
        (ms > 99 ? ms : ms > 9 ? "0" + ms : "00" + ms);
};

$( document ).ready(function() {
    start();
});

</script>

<input type="hidden" id="display-area" value="">

<button id="toggle-button" onClick="stop()">SUBMIT<br>RESULT</button>
```

As any one can change the hidden value by inspecting the element we are not able to run this puzzle successfully. Kindly advice how to avoid users to change the timer value and let me know how to save the timer value in mysql db using php.

Answer (score 0):

I think Ajax would be your answer.

Comment: Right now i am using the ajax functionality only, but to send the value through ajax i need to get value from the hidden field. The stopwatch will keep on running until the user submit. The final value will get stored in hidden field. that's my problem.